# Rclusterpp.hclust not providing correct clusters when using cutree

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I have a fairly large dataset of about 75,000 observations and 7 columns which consist of alarm data details which `stats:hclust` cannot support (crashes `RStudio`). From a few searches I found `Rclusterpp.hclust` which is reported to reduce the complexity and resource allocation for Hierarchical Clustering, so I gave it a try. It takes about 5 mins or so and does provide a dendrogram, but if I attempt to use `cutree` and specify either a height or a number of clusters I get strange results. I see this same problem when using a small sample of 38 observations as demonstrated below. Am I doing something wrong or is this an issue with the Rclusterpp.hclust package? (running package 3.4.1 in R 3.4.1)

Sample dataset looks like this:

```
dataset
#   DAY COUNT LOCATION M1 M2 HOURS SOURCE
#1  238     2   222307  1  1  5437   1008
#2  238     1   222307  2  1  5437   1008
#3  238     5   222307  3  2  5437   1008
#4  238     2   222307  4  3  5437   1008
#5  238    14   222307  5  1  5437   1008
#6  238     4   222307  5  1  5437   1008
#7  238    14   222307  6  2  5437   1008
#8  238     3   222307  1  1  5437   1008
#9  238     1   222307  2  1  5437   1008
#10 238     1   222307  4  3  5437   1008
#11 238     2   222307  4  3  5437   1008
#12 238     2   222307  4  3  5437   1008
#13 238     5   222307  5  1  5437   1008
#14 238    11   222307  5  1  5437   1008
#15 238     1   222307  5  1  5437   1008
#16 238     3   222307  5  1  5437   1008
#17 238    18   222307  6  2  5437   1008
#18 238     2   222307  7  4  5437      9
#19 238     2   222307  8  4  5437     10
#20 238     3   222307  9  5  5437   1008
#21 238     2   222307 10  6  5437    865
#22 238     9   222307 11  7  5437     10
#23 238     2   222307 12  7  5437     10
#24 238     1   222307 12  7  5437     10
#25 238     5   222307 11  7  5437     10
#26 238     2   222307  8  4  5437     10
#27 238     3   222307 13  8  5437    864
#28 238     3   222307 14  8  5437    864
#29 238     1   222307 11  7  5437     10
#30 238     3   222307 11  7  5437     10
#31 238     2   222307 15  7  5437     10
#32 238     5   222307 11  7  5437     10
#33 238     2   222307 16  7  5437     10
#34 238     2   222307 17  7  5437     10
#35 238     3   222307 18  7  5437     10
#36 238     2   222307 15  7  5437     10
#37 238     6   222307 11  7  5437     10
#38 238     3   222307 19  7  5437     10
```

`DAY`,`HOURS` and `COUNT` are real numeric values, whereas `LOCATION`,`M1`,`M2` and `SOURCE` are numerically coded categorical values.

Using stats:hclust I can get a cluster which does represent the data well and does distinguish the 2 primary clusters of alarm events among all observations in this sample as expected (i.e. the observation numbers in the dendrogram are alarms that should be grouped together):

```
d1 <- dist((as.matrix(scale(dataset))))
hc1 <- hclust(d1, method = "single")
cutree(hc1,2)
# 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 #27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 
# 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  2  1  1  2  2  2  2  2  #1  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2 
plot(hc1)
```

[image: HC1 Clusters]

However if I do the same in `Rclusterpp:hclust` I get more clusters than what I am specifying (In this case I got 3 when I asked for 2 as shown in this small sample). When I run this on my large dataset I get almost 20,000 clusters when only asking for a few.

```
d2 <- dist((as.matrix(scale(dataset))))
hc2 <- Rclusterpp.hclust(d2, method = "single")
cutree(hc2,2)
# 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 #27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 
# 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  2  1  1  1  1  1  3  3  1  1  3  3  3  3  3  #1  1  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3 
plot(hc2)
```

[image: HC2 Clusters]

Any idea why this is happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have looked into this a little and it appears that the return value of `Rclusterpp.hclust` is not fully aligned (wrt. the `merge` matrix) with `stats'` `hclust`.

From the documentation of `hclust`, the `merge` component of the returned list is:

> an n-1 by 2 matrix. Row i of merge describes the merging of clusters at step i of the clustering. If an element j in the row is negative, then observation -j was merged at this stage. If j is positive then the merge was with the cluster formed at the (earlier) stage j of the algorithm. Thus negative entries in merge indicate agglomerations of singletons, and positive entries indicate agglomerations of non-singletons.

For the `C` implementation of `cutree`, it seems that the word in parentheses (`earlier`) is important.

Looking at `head(hc2$merge)`, we see the following:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   -2   -9
[2,]  -25  -32
[3,]  -31  -36
[4,]  -19  -26
[5,]   -4    6
[6,]  -11  -12
```

So on the fifth row, there is a "pointer" to the sixth step, which is **going in an unexpected direction**.

If instead we would re-arrange the `merge` component (swapping the rows and "pointers"), things look ok:

```
# non-generic replacements for specific data example
hc3 <- hc2
hc3$merge[5, ] <- c(-11,-12)
hc3$merge[6, ] <- c(-4,5)
hc3$merge[13, ] <- c(-10,6)
cutree(hc3, 2)
```

You could write a function to handle this re-structuring of the `merge` matrix, such that things always work as you would like (maybe a wrapper around `cutree`).

Finally note that there is an issue on Github about this, where you can find some discussion and cross-package comparison:
https://github.com/nolanlab/Rclusterpp/issues/4